# Overwriting lines in files in Visual C++

Tags: file, visual-c++, lines, overwrite

I need a way to write over lines in a specific file. As it is currently, I basically write to a file, then what I need to do is re-open the file, go back to a specific line in that file, and continue writing from there, overwriting whatever was there before it. Any information on how to do so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently I'm using a StreamWriter to write to the files.

Comment: Also, for an added challenge, I'm using memory-managed Visual C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out finally. Easiest way I found to do this was to read the lines of the file into a buffer and stop reading them in once you hit a specific marker that you're looking for. From there, you wipe the file and re-write the lines in the buffer to it. From there, you can continue writing from where you left off. This is only really a good idea for smaller files.